# In Thunderbird, how to make Quick Filter "body" search on server?

Tags: email, thunderbird, search, imap

Thunderbird 102.3.1 (64-bit) on Fedora.

I've set up my server to offer server-side full-text search (FTS) including an index for much faster searching.

Thunderbird's Quick Filter search box is painstakingly slow on larger mailing list folders when used to search the body of emails for a keyword.

The whole point of setting up an FTS indexer and search engine on my IMAP server was to make that bearably fast, as I need to work daily with it¹. So, the "search messages… " dialog is not an option here, even if it *does* have a "search on server" checkbox that indeed works fast now.

So:

How do I force Thunderbird to do the body searches in the Quick Filter field on the server?

Local searching is *not* an option.

Comment: ¹ Using the message search dialog is cumbersome and honestly, GUI-wise so 1990's that it hurts, as it reinvents the folder message list, and badly so, omitting context menus and instead having exactly the actions I don't need as buttons at the bottom instead.

Comment: Which email server are you using?

Comment: my own, that's a dovecot with [fts-xapian](https://github.com/grosjo/fts-xapian/)

Comment: Already [11 years ago](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=564168#c15) Quick Search didn't use the FTS. Seems like nothing was done since then to address this complaint.

Comment: @harrymc are there addon options?

Comment: Quick search works only on messages indexed locally by Thunderbird, so is horribly slow in your case. The Search messages dialog (Ctrl+Shift+F) seems to be the only solution. Add-ons seem very trivial, such as [Search Button](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/search-button/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative answer : Quick search in Thunderbird works only on messages
that are locally indexed, so is horribly slow in your case.

This problem was evoked 13 years ago in bug report 564168
[RFE: Option to run all searches on the server when using an IMAP server](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=564168#c15),
where the last answer from 11 years ago was:

> GLODA search is not used by Quick Search(search box in Quick Filter Bar, Ctrl+Shift+K), Edit/Find/Search Messages(Search Messages of folder context menu), nor Saved Search Folder. And indexing is not used in these ordinal/non-GLODA search even when "Global Indexer and Search" is enabled, because of Non-GLODA seach.

The Search messages dialog (Ctrl+Shift+F) seems to be the only solution.
Add-ons seem very trivial, such as
[Search Button](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-us/thunderbird/addon/search-button/),
and do not offer a better solution.

You could perhaps use a keyboard macro program to make using the
Search messages dialog less painful, such as
[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)
on Firefox or
[Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).